# Understanding x86-64 assembly code in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, x86-64

I don't have a lot of experience working with assembly or x86-64, and I'm having trouble understanding this assembly code provided by Xcode while debugging an iOS version-specific bug:

```
0x108f5607a <+18>:  movq   0x3fe98f(%rip), %rsi      ; "intrinsicContentSize"
0x108f56081 <+25>:  movq   0x47c158(%rip), %r12      ; (void *)0x000000010b4aa800: objc_msgSend
0x108f56088 <+32>:  callq  *%r12
0x108f5608b <+35>:  movsd  %xmm0, -0x30(%rbp)
0x108f56090 <+40>:  movsd  %xmm1, -0x28(%rbp)
0x108f56095 <+45>:  movq   0x426ea4(%rip), %rsi      ; "_contentHuggingPriorities"
0x108f5609c <+52>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108f5609f <+55>:  callq  *%r12
0x108f560a2 <+58>:  movsd  %xmm0, -0x40(%rbp)
0x108f560a7 <+63>:  movsd  %xmm1, -0x38(%rbp)
0x108f560ac <+68>:  movq   0x426e9d(%rip), %rsi      ; "_contentCompressionResistancePriorities"
0x108f560b3 <+75>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x108f560b6 <+78>:  callq  *%r12
0x108f560b9 <+81>:  movsd  %xmm0, -0x50(%rbp)
0x108f560be <+86>:  movsd  %xmm1, -0x48(%rbp)
```

Thanks to the assembly code comments, I can guess that 3 messages are being sent:

- `[obj intrinsicContentSize]`
- `[obj _contentHuggingPriorities]`
- `[obj _contentCompressionResistance]`

I don't understand what the `movsd` instructions are for, however. Is this to copy the return value of the above method calls to a register for use in the current function? If yes, then is it correct to assume that the results for calling `intrinsicContentSize` and `_contentHuggingPriorities` are overwritten by the results of `_contentCompressionResistance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this to copy the return value of the above method calls **to a register** for use in the current function?

No, the opposite.  `movsd  %xmm0, -0x40(%rbp)` is a store **from** xmm0 to a local on the stack.  In AT&T syntax, the destination comes last.  (Operand list is reversed vs. Intel syntax.  If you're more familiar with Intel syntax, set your debugger to show disassembly in Intel syntax).

In this code: `r12` holds a function pointer to `objc_msgSend`, and three calls are made with it.  Your disassembler has usefully provided symbol names for the static locations being accessed with RIP-relative addressing modes.

The relevant part of the x86-64 System V calling convention:

- integer args in RDI and RSI, in that order.  Arg-passing registers are call-clobbered.  (Only 2 args are passed to this function, so RDX, RCX, R8, R9 aren't used).
- RBX is call-preserved, and this code is using it to re-init the first arg-passing register (RDI) with the same value for all three calls.  (Assuming that RBX = RDI before the first; you don't show that).
- Two FP return values, or a struct, returned in %xmm0 and %xmm1.
- All xmm/ymm/zmm registers are call-clobbered, so FP values have to be spilled across function calls, not simply copied to a call-preserved register (because there aren't any).

Comment: You're right, there's a `movq   %rdi, %rbx` right before the above snippet.